# проблема с иконками fontawesome MacOs google Chrome

Tags: html, css, fontawesome

Всем добрый день! В кратце проблема такая, есть страница, на ней шрифтовые иконки fontawesome, сам шрифт подключается через CND

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

иконки через псевдоэллементы :after :before

```
&:before
                        content: '\f00c'
                        color: #ffffff
                        font-family: "FontAwesome", "Font Awesome 5 Free"
                        margin-right: 10px
                        font-weight: 100
                        font-size: 1.625em
                        display: inline-block
                        font-style: normal
                        font-variant: normal
                        text-rendering: auto
                        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
```

на windows отображаются во всех браузерах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На Mac отображается во всех браузерах кроме Chrome (тестировал на разных сервисах)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Хроме галочки становятся такими вот квадратами, остальные иконки на странице, кроме галочек, рендеряться нормально, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Подскажите как можно решить, чтобы иконка осталась на странице шрифтом, спасибо.

ошибка в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а нет ли в консоли браузера ошибок загрузки?

Comment: да есть, ajax-loader.gif:1 как исправить?

Comment: ну со шрифтом это не связано. просто нет гифки загрузчика или неправильно указан её путь

Comment: с cdn у вас грузится css, а сам шрифт грузится?

Comment: напомню, что во всех других браузерах загружаются все иконки, не работает только галочка на MacOs и только в хроме, из этого можно сделать вывод что шрифт точно грузится, а на счет того что не правильно указан путь - не совсем понял что за путь? и почему тогда в других браузерах и OS этот путь находит?

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего проблема в аттрибуте стиля font-weight. В подгружаемом css файлы шрифта указаны для font-weight:

- normal
- 400
- 900

попробуйте в своем стиле поставить

```
font-weight: normal
```

Comment: нет, проблема не в этом